# How to check locale against message.properties

Tags: java, locale, resteasy

I am using hibernate and RestEasy API to make a server. i have 3 properties files `message.properties a, mesage_en-GB.properties and message_en.propperties` files. 
When I get a request from client , it have locale in header param. I need to check this locale against my properties file, i.e. if it is en-GB than use  mesage_en-GB.properties, if not given than use message.properties, and if wrong enter than give error message.
but am not getting how to compare these values.
please suggest.

Comment: So you're getting REST request via RestEasy and receiving an HTTP Header, and on the server side you need to choose which properties to use -- do I get it right?

Comment: yes..i need to compare HTTP heaer with properties file and have to select which file to choose.

Answer (score 1):

If locales and bundles can't be managed by a container for some reason you will need to manage them manually.

I assume you have property files in your classpath.

First of all you need to create the Locale that you're going to use. For example you get language from HTTP header as String `fr`, you pass it to [Locale.forLanguageTag(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#forLanguageTag%28java.lang.String%29)  method in Java7 or use [Locale(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale%28java.lang.String%29) constructor in Java6 and get Locale object:

```
Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(stringFromHeader) // since Java 7
Locale locale = new Locale(stringFromHeader) // prior to Java 7
```

Then you pass this locale to the [ResourceBundle.getBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) method to get the right bundle:

```
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", locale);
```

Then you call ResourceBundle's [getString(key:String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29) method to get localized String:

```
messages.getString("my_message")
```

---

To make sure that this method 100% works you can follow the next simple steps:

1) Create a folder `tmp` somewhere

2) In that folder create file `A.java` with the following contents:

```
import java.util.*;

public class A {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Locale locale = new Locale("en");
  ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", locale);
  System.out.println(messages.getString("my_message"));
  locale = new Locale("fr");
  messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", locale);
  System.out.println(messages.getString("my_message"));
}   
}
```

3) Create file `messages.properties` with the following contents:

```
my_message=hello
```

4) Create file `messages_fr.properties` with the following contents:

```
my_message=salut
```

5) Go to `tmp` folder and run two commands:

```
javac A.java
java -cp . A
```

The output is:

```
hello
salut
```

I hope that is does work for you!

PS:
There is a great walk-through here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html

Comment: this is exactly what am doing. But in place of Locale.forLanguageTag(stringFromHeader) am using new Locale(stringFromHeader) , and even if am getting xyz in stringFromHeader then too getting msgs from messages.properties file.

Comment: and secondly am not getting Locale.forLanguageTag() method, there is no such method for Local class

Comment: @Romi edited my answer, added notes about forLanguageTag() being present only in the latest Java

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register a `LocaleChangeInterceptor` in Spring configuration and use `<spring:message>` tag to output messages.

Here's a great walkthrough: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/07/spring-3-mvc-internationalization-i18n-localization-tutorial-example.html

PS
This mechanism can change from server to server, in some cases using `<fmt:message>` could be a better alternative.

Comment: Qwe: thanks for answring. but that not what I require. i think u dint get my point. actually am making a serever and based upon client locale will give result. now i need to compare locale(sent by client to with message.properties or message_en-GB.prperties.)

Comment: In the original version of your question you said you were using Spring MVC and I got your point right, now you're using RestEasy and I got your point wrong

Comment: Yup at one point,by mistake I write it as spring MVC, sorry for that. Now can you please suggest me how can i resolve this probelm.